# Can I gain all of the achievements in one playthrough?

Tags: achievements, the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Are all of the achievements in *Elder Scrolls: Skyrim* able to be acquired in a single playthrough, or will I have to save at strategic times to be able to step back to earlier points?

I'm assuming that if it's anything like *Oblivion*, that you are able to join multiple guilds one after another and complete their questlines and move to another.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few achievements tied to the main quest which have you joining either the Stormcloaks OR the Imperial Legion, but these are awarded for picking *either* path, rather than siding with one group over the other (as in Dragon Age: Origins, for instance).

All of these achievements should be attainable in a single playthrough:

```
Unbound (10g) - Complete "Unbound"
Bleak Falls Barrow (10g) - Complete "Bleak Falls Barrow"
The Way of the Voice (20g) - Complete "The Way of the Voice"
Diplomatic Immunity (20g) - Complete "Diplomatic Immunity"
Alduin's Wall (20g) - Complete "Alduin's Wall"
Elder Knowledge (20g) - Complete "Elder Knowledge"
The Fallen (20g) - Complete "The Fallen"
Dragonslayer (50g) - Complete "Dragonslayer"
Take Up Arms (10g) - Join the Companions
Blood Oath (10g) - Become a member of the Circle
Glory of the Dead (30g) - Complete "Glory of the Dead"
Gatekeeper (10g) - Join the College of Winterhold
Revealing the Unseen (10g) - Complete "Revealing the Unseen"
The Eye of Magnus (30g) - Complete "The Eye of Magnus"
Taking Care of Business (10g) - Join the Thieves Guild
Darkness Returns (10g) - Complete "Darkness Returns"
One with the Shadows (30g) - Returned the Thieves Guild to its former glory
With Friends Like These... (10g) - Join the Dark Brotherhood
Bound Until Death (10g) - Complete" Bound Until Death"
Hail Sithis! (30g) - Complete "Hail Sithis!"
Taking Sides (10g) - Join the Stormcloaks or the Imperial Army
War Hero (10g) - Capture Fort Sunguard or Fort Greenwall
Hero of Skyrim (30g) - Capture Solitude or Windhelm
Sideways (20g) - Complete 10 side quests
Hero of the People (30g) - Complete 30 Misc Objectives
Hard Worker (10g) - Chop wood, mine ore, and cook food
Thief (30g) - Pick 50 locks and 50 pockets
Snake Tongue (10g) - Successfully persuade, bribe, and intimidate
Blessing (10g) - Select a Standing Stone blessing
Standing Stones (30g) - Find 13 Standing Stones
Citizen (10g) - Buy a house
Wanted (10g) - Escape from jail
Married (10g) - Get married
Artificer (10g) - Make a smithed item, an enchanted item, and a potion
Master Criminal (20g) - Bounty of 1000 gold in all nine holds
Golden Touch (30g) - Have 100,000 gold
Delver (40g) - Clear 50 dungeons
Skill Master (40g) - Get a skill to 100
Explorer (40g) - Discover 100 locations
Reader (20g) - Read 50 Skill Books
Daedric Influence (10g) - Acquire a Daedric Artifact
Oblivion Walker (30g) - Collect 15 Daedric Artifacts
Dragon Soul (10g) - Absorb a dragon soul
Dragon Hunter (20g) - Absorb 20 dragon souls
Words of Power (10g) - Learn all three words of a shout
Thu'um Master (40g) - Learn 20 shouts
Apprentice (5g) - Reach Level 5
Adept (10g) - Reach Level 10
Expert (25g) - Reach Level 25
Master (50g) - Reach Level 50
```

Answer (score 3):

With the Dawnguard DLC, it is not possible, because there are two separate achievements for choosing the vampire side and the werewolf side.

Comment: The question was asked before the DLC was released, which implies they were asking about the vanilla version of the game.

Comment: @Vemonus Nonetheless, the base game includes DLC achievements even if you don't own them

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer they're kept separately, usually, but fair point. I'm not sure why this was downvoted, though.